# astyanax TokenRangeOfflineException when connecting to two node cluster

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

I have some fairly simple code written to experiment with astyanax.  It works fine when talking to a single node Cassandra db on localhost, but when I write the same schema to a two node cluster (which is definitely accessible from my host), I get a `TokenRangeOfflineException`.

What am I missing?

```
AstyanaxContext.Builder builder = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
            .forKeyspace("myKeyspace")
            .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
                    .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.NONE)
            )
            .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
                    .setPort(9160)
                    .setMaxConnsPerHost(5)
                    .setSeeds("host1.domain.com,host2.domain.com")
            )
            .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor());
```

produces this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TokenRangeOfflineException: TokenRangeOfflineException: [host=host1.domain.com, latency=59(94), attempts=1]UnavailableException()
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:165)
com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TokenRangeOfflineException: TokenRangeOfflineException: [host=host1.domain.com, latency=59(94), attempts=1]UnavailableException()
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:165)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$1$2.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:200)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
```

Comment: Have the same issue, can you explain what you did ? maybe it will help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try w/ [NodeDiscoveryType.RING_DESCRIBE](http://netflix.github.com/astyanax/javadoc/com/netflix/astyanax/connectionpool/NodeDiscoveryType.html#RING_DESCRIBE)

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that without success, but I went back and did it again with a few more changes and it worked (though I don't exactly know why).  I'll post what I did separately.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, partly.  I got it to work by making several changes.  I'm not sure why the simple case doesn't work, but the following did.

First, I replaced my keyspace, which was created with defaults  (create keyspace foo), like this:

```
create keyspace foo with placement_strategy = 'NetworkTopologyStrategy'
    AND strategy_options={DC1:1};
```

That changes the output of "nodetool describering foo" such that endpoint_details has something in it.  I had previously stepped through the debugger and noticed that endpoint_details being empty was a cause of some failures once I switched my astyanax config to look like this:

```
 AstyanaxContext.Builder builder = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
            .forCluster("myCluster")
            .forKeyspace("foo")
            .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
                    .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.RING_DESCRIBE)
                    .setConnectionPoolType(ConnectionPoolType.TOKEN_AWARE)
            )
            .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
                    .setPort(9160)
                    .setMaxConnsPerHost(5)
                    .setInitConnsPerHost(1)
                    .setSeeds("host1,host2")
            )
            .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new Slf4jConnectionPoolMonitorImpl());
```

I would love to see some documentation that describes configuration options recommended for common cluster/keyspace settings.  I'm sure it's obvious to the cognoscenti, but for noobs, it's a little opaque.

Comment: fwiw, i have seen this error when creating a keyspace with one consistency level (say CL_ONE), and then from another client getting the keyspace but specifying a different consistency level (say CL_TWO).